# Is using Tor in .tar.xz file right in Xubuntu?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, ubuntu

On [this page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu) it is written that one should not use packages in Ubuntu universe as they are not reliably updated. I have .tar.xz file from where I extracted Tor and using it. And when checked Firefox ESR said it is up to date. Ver. 24.2.0. So ?

PS I think .tar.xz is a kind of package.

Answer (score 1):

The current version for Linux should be `tor-browser-linux32-3.5_en-US.tar.xz` for the 32-bit version (replace 32 with 64 for the 64-bit version), so it sounds like you have it right.

Essentially `.tar.xz` means that you have a [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) file that has been compressed using the [xz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz) method. You can think of this as being similar to downloading a [zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) file and extracting that the same way. The Tor Project use `.zip` files for Mac releases and `.tar.xz` files for Linux.

Ubuntu does have Tor releases in their "Universe" repository, and this may be easier to install, but it often lags behind the official Tor Project releases so may have unpatched security problems. You're also unable to verify the package signature when downloading over APT.

Comment: Windows users get a .exe for their bundles, it used to be .zip, but people got confused.